# Android custom toast: TextColor set to black but has red shadow

Tags: android, toast

I have a little issue with a custom toast: the toast itself and the positioning of the three textviews work as expected. I set black for one textview and green for the other. The green one is green, the one with black textcolor (on darkgray background) however is a mixture of black and red. In fact, the inner text is black with a red shadow. 
Any explanation for this behavior?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mytoast_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/toast_frame">

<LinearLayout 
 android:orientation="horizontal"     
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

 android:weightSum="100" 
 android:layout_weight="90" 

 android:background="#444444" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/leftview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="50"

    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:textColor = "#000000"
    android:textAppearance="@style/myToast_small"
    android:shadowColor="#BB0000"
    android:shadowRadius="2.75" />

 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/rightview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"        
    android:layout_weight="50"

    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:textColor = "#00FF00"
    android:textAppearance="@style/myToast_small"
    android:shadowColor="#BB0000"
    android:shadowRadius="2.75" />      
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      

    android:gravity="center_horizontal"

    android:textAppearance="@style/myToast_small"

    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:shadowColor="#BB0000"
    android:shadowRadius="2.75" />
 </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably has to do with this code on each of the `TextView`s:

```
android:shadowColor="#BB0000"
android:shadowRadius="2.75"
```

If you don't want the red shadow, you'll probably want to remove that.

Comment: Sadly I had that - but in the lib and not the code I tested on the phone and copied here. Classical human error, it's late and I am watching TV while coding :/

Comment: @MarkusProske It happens to the best of us--I've said plenty a time "I *know* it's not <insert simple thing here>", then it is. No worries. :)